# how to stretch the sourrounding of padded area in nine-patch image without the content area?

Tags: android, android-layout, nine-patch

How do I keep the content are as the red part no matter how wide the nine patch background stretches to.

Please see this "zoomed" example image:

**Notice: the red part is a virtual illustration for the content area**

[image]

This is a handle for a SlidingDrawer for comments.

This image is ok on portrait view, but in landscape the virtual (red) area expands such that when I write some text and center it it appears beside the green tab not in the center of the green tab

Here is how it looks like in portrait and in landscape (Please notice the red part is virtual just to illustrate the content area).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the 9-patch tool you defined the top patch area **outside** the red content area.
You can define a split patch area. Try covering some red and covering some of the picture's right side.
Your left patch seems too big too. Try this:

[image]

Comment: No, that's not what I'm aiming for, I found out that what I'm trying to achieve cannot be done by 9 patch I should use a background bottom repeater and a separate image for the tab to keep the tab's size, and avoid its expansion